# Can't access components in form from a different class

Tags: c#

I've created a normal form with one button

```
namespace MultiServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int i;//this I can access because it's global public

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 13);
            ListenForConnections lfc = new ListenForConnections(listener, this);

        }
    }
}
```

In the `ListenForConnections`-class I have access to int `i` since it is not protected. However, why is my button protected within the class `Form1`?  Is there anyway making all components accessible via the `ListenForConnections`-class?

```
namespace MultiServer
{

    class ListenForConnections
    {
        Form1 form;
        TcpListener listener;

        public ListenForConnections(TcpListener l, Form1 f)
        {
            this.listener = l;
            this.form = f;
            form.i = 10;

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I create an instance of `Form1` and declare it in the constructor.
I can access the variable, but not the button.

I am aware that I can create internal methods to update the components within the main class(form1), but I've googled Internal Methods, and there was no clear understanding of it.

I would appreciate some help, even it's a little.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I'm really sorry about that, I thought it would help differentiate the language from java script and other languages that maybe mistaken for.

Comment: the button click event is private.. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Your design smells. Your `ListenForConnections` should not need access to a specific form, because that means you can't ever reuse it for another form. Explain what you want the class to do.

Comment: Besides that your design is a bit quirky (accessing physical buttons and no abstractions ...), you should know that Visual Studio generates a designer-class (partial class to your `Form1`) where all the gui-controls reside as (if I remember correctly) protected.

Comment: @Pogrindis the button click is private yes, but I don't need access to it. I'm trying to get access to components in my form, for example, a text box from this class.

Comment: The pass the _value_ of `yourform.TextBox.Text` to the class, not the form itself.

Comment: @codeCaster Well, I'm going to start a thread and pass in the that classes method. So the thread will keep running the method and accept multiple clients.

Comment: @CodeCaster so I should pass the text box it self, instead of the form? I don't know why I didn't think of that. I've been doing a lot of Java stuff lately, and it's possible to send an instance of the GUI class so that's what I've been doing a lot.

Comment: If you don't care about the implication of changing controls' modifiers to public and just want to do that, then see the duplicate.

Comment: @CodeCaster so passing an instance of a `TextBox` to another `class` will create a new instance? I'm not using the `new` Keyword, so it shouldn't duplicate in theory.

Comment: I mean that your question has been asked before, see [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972061/c-sharp-accessing-winform-control-properties-from-another-class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can do that by changing "Modifiers" property of the button in design view.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you usually don't want to. There's a reason controls aren't public by default.

Comment: You are right but if the Project has only one form I think changing it to public will not cause a problem.

Comment: It won't cause _problems_ per se, but it's a design smell. It hampers testability and reusability.

Comment: @CodeCaster this is what I was looking for, I only have one form, so it should not be a problem right?

Comment: @Moynul I changed all my buttons to public when I have a lot of forms and I didn't have any problem. You are writing codes. If you are careful no problem.

Comment: @OrkunBekar thanks for the reassurance, this is what I meant by question, getting access to the forms components such as text boxes, labels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

try setting the `Modifiers` property. However this should not be done this way. If you want to run the code of `button` event then move the code to a function and call that function from both `button` and your `class`.